# How to access the element in MongoDB Table?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

I am sorry for the ignorance. I am very new to `MongoDB` as I come from MySQL background.

I would like to know how to query to get a unique value in MongoDB`.

[image]
This is how my Table looks. I would like to access the `value` Sapnaedu by querying for field name `param`='sitename'

I tried the following :

```
var params = keystone.list("Parameters1");
var a = params.model.findOne({'param':'sitename'});
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to query with param(sitename) and get the value(SapnaEdu) only. . .

Which you can do with the select method as mentioned below and exclude the fields you don't want with - (exlude symbol).

```
var a = params.model.findOne({'param':'sitename'}).select('value -_id');
```

Hope it helps, let me know if I misunderstood.
Just a suggestion, it is better to use ID for query to keep it unique and specific.